# Using zsh alias to quickly clone a git repository with custom folder name

Tags: zsh, git, alias, oh-my-zsh

I want an alias shortcut to achieve the following:

1. Clone a github repository with a custom folder name
2. Open it in my fav text editor (atom)

I currently use this inside `~/.zshrc`:

`alias quickstart="git clone https://github.com/myname/quickstart-html-template.git new_html_project && atom new_html_project"`

Can I parameterize `new_html_project`?

Comment: Why was bash tagged on this Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define parameters in an alias, you need to use a function:

```
quickstart() {
    git clone https://github.com/myname/quickstart-html-template.git "$1" && atom "$1"
}
```

Add that to your `.zshrc` instead of the alias definition.